# Prism not working in WP7.1 but working in WP8

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, prism

I have developed a Windows Phone application using MVVM (Prism v4.1).
Everything is working fine when I deploy it to the `Emulator WVGA` or my HTC 8X but when I deply it to my Lumia 800 or use the `Emulator 7.1` it isn't working.

Here is one part of the view(model) hope it helps a bit

`View`

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="LearnByTranslate.Views.PhrasePracticeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:LearnByTranslate.Infrastructure.Convverters"

    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="24,0,24,72" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel x:Name="stkPracticeContent" Margin="0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtTextToTranslate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding EnglishPhrase,Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="40" FontStyle="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource EnglishSentenceStyle}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light">
                    <TextBlock.Foreground>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundColor}"/>
                    </TextBlock.Foreground>
                </TextBlock>               
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid> 
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

`ViewModel`

```
class PhrasePracticeViewModel : NotificationObject
{       
    private string _englishPhrase;     

    public PhrasePracticeViewModel()
    {

    }       

    public string EnglishPhrase
    {
        get { return _englishPhrase; }
        set
        {
            _englishPhrase = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => EnglishPhrase);
        }
    }       
}
```

Everything is working fine (regarding the binding in the other views) except for this view.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is wrong once the view is shown. Can you provide more details? You have Convverters spelled wrong, but it isn't used you can remove that namespace. Maybe styles are not properly included.

Comment: The problem is that the label is not show at all but I know that the EnglishPhrase property is populated (even the space where the word should be shown is missing). As I sad. It's working on WP8 emulator but not on WP7.1

I also have some buttons and other things on this view but non of the bindings is working in WP7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the strangest things I have ever seen.

The reasone for this was that my ViewModel class wasn't made `public` (as you can see above). I'll look into this a little deeper why this works on WP8 but not on WP7.1 but it really frustrated me.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Great you managed to fix it eventually. I had problems with binding and forgetting to make properties public...but why would it work on one emulator and not the other one puzzles me also.

Comment: Not only on phones put also on the device (Lumia 800 and HTC 8X). I'll send an email and see if I can get something from it.